# Converting from simpleAdapter to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter

I have built myself an app with a list in it. Until now i have used a `SimpleAdapter` to populate the list, but i decided to move to an `ArrayAdapter`. Problem is, i can't figure how to populate the `ArrayAdapter` in the same way! Here is the way i used my `SimpleAdapter`:

```
adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[]{"name", "current", "reset"},  new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
```

My listItems variable is actually setup like this:

```
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Now, when trying to use the `ArrayAdapter` constructor with the same arguments, it give me an error. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, when trying to use the ArrayAdapter constructor with the same
>   arguments, it give me an error.

That is because an `ArrayAdapter` is designed for very simple scenarios where the data is in the form of a list/array with only a single widget(usually a `TextView`) to bind to. As you have three widgets in your layout you'll need to extend the `ArrayAdapter` class to bind your data as it can't do that on its own with the default implementation, something like this:

```
listView.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this, R.layout.custom_row_view,
                    R.id.text1, listItems) {

                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
                            View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                            final HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);
                            TextView firstText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                            firstText.setText(item.get("corresponding_key"));
                            TextView secondText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                            secondText.setText(item.get("corresponding_key"));
                            TextView thirdText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                            thirdText.setText(item.get("corresponding_key"));
                            return rowView;
                        }

            });
```

But in the end there is the question why do you want to use `ArrayAdapter`, when the `SimpleAdapter` is more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: There are probably at least 50 questions on stackoverflow asking how do make changes to some data inside a listview with very few answers. Your answer to this question also answers those 50 questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining an ArrayAdapter like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
  "Linux", "OS/2" };

// Define a new Adapter
// First parameter - Context
// Second parameter - Layout for the row
// Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
// Fourth - the Array of data

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I know this, but i have my own layout as you can see above, and more than one `R.id.text$`. Please look at my update, since my values are also stored in a `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think you can use an ArrayAdapter like that; you'll have to implement a custom adapter that derives from BaseAdapter. Why not just use a GridView if you need columns?